# Increment integers by one and ternary operator

Tags: python, c, increment, ternary-operator, post-increment

I am new to Python, how can I do the following C idiom in Python?

```
i += 1

i++

i = (j == 2)? 1 : 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you actually intend to do? Smells like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Python:

```
i += 1

i += 1

i = 1 if j == 2 else 0
```